# How to achieve the role played by "public static variables of Java" in JavaScript or a webpage?

Tags: javascript

On my homepage I have to set a cookie using the name of the logged in user. The cookie `set` and `get` part has to be done in JS. On the subsequent sub pages I have to retrieve the `cookie(username)` using the `set` variable name.

How can I store the username/cookie name so that it is publicly accessible across all the pages? This username will obviously change with each new user and is not constant.

I have tried doing this using external JS file but in every new page the value is reset to default which I don't want.

The exact solution to my problem is like the work done by:

```
public static variable
```

in Java (not final). I want to achieve this in JS.

Comment: Please post your code that isn't working. You should be able to get this work with cookies; you're probably not setting them correctly.

Comment: And note: Javascript has no equivalent of `public static` or `final` in cookies. Your code could possible make use of some `getter`/`setter` functionality, though. That's why we need to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in Javascript unless you use a storage API (client side storage, or cookies, or something like that). The reason is that when you move from one page to another, it doesn't particularly matter to the browser. It wipes its slate and starts over, keeping explicitly stored data like cookies and such, and deleting everything else that is dynamically created. So the short of it is, if you want each page to know the name, you have to include the name in each page's code (manually or via script).

Comment: I am aware. However, the OP wants to retain the *name* of the cookie across pages. Even though the cookie is there, without the name it's effectively inaccessible to the JS. I am simply saying that you have to know the name, since JS variables are not carried across pages.

Comment: Well, that's not how I read it (why would the stored variable name change? Can you do that in Javascript?).

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Sajid has rightly interpreted my problem.
the current code to get my app working is like this.
I have an external JS file.

---Content of externalfile.js----
       function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays){    //body }

function getCookie(c_name){ //body }
..
the external file is linked.
Home page uses it as Setcookie("User", <somevalue>, NumberOfDays);
here the cookie is set using the CONSTANT var name "User" which I dont want.
All the subpages, use getCookie("User");

Comment: Instead I want to declare a variable in external.js, assign it a 
cookie name in home page and use it as a cookie name. 
By this I can use the username of the signed in user to set and read cookie.

In my current implementation, the cookie variable name is constant which I need to specify in every page.
If I have to change variable name for some reason it will be annoying. 
I hope now I am more clear with the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know your application. In javascript you have function prototypes. In a function prototype you can declare 'static' members like so:
function C(params for constructor){
    C.aStaticVariable = 5;
}
alert(C.aStaticVariable); //available everywhere

Comment: Its something like this that I want in my code. I tried your method, it works only within the page, value doesnt persists across pages. I want the cookie VARIABLE name to persist so that i can refer them to set or retrieve cookie across pages.  Though I had placed this code in an external JS file and included everywhere, the variable was not accessible in the pages.